# Using dictionaries for sentiment analysis in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, bigdata, apache-spark-sql, sentiment-analysis

At the very beginning I would like to say that I am new at programming. I spent a lot of time transforming my data set but then I stuck. The goal is to make a sentiment analysis for a time period of 2011-2019 in PySpark.

What I want to do is to check whether there is a negative or positive sentiment for the statement in column `Body`. This data is stored in one data frame. To get proper sentiment analysis I will use the **Loughran-McDonald Sentiment Word List** - as the text within `Body` will contain some (or many) finance jargon. The dictionary with words and assigned sentiment is stored in a second data frame. Each of the data frames (one with column: 'Body' and second with the LM dictionary) contains thousands of rows (ca 80 ths. each).

To do the sentiment analysis, I have to iterate through each row in the first data frame by column `Body` using the words from the second data frame --> looking whether particular word exist in the sentence stored in column 'Body'. Having in mind that there may be both negative and positive words in one sentence, let's assume that one 'negative' word equals -1 and one positive word in a sentence equals +1. The final result (sum of `n(-1)/(+1)p` words) will be stored in new column in the first data frame.

For example - if a particular row in `Body` contains the word `abandon`, which is tagged `negative` (in the second df the number not equal 0 (in this case 2009) means that the word is assigned to particular column of sentiment - in this case: negative) the result in new column should be -1. Hope that I described my problem in an understandable way.

Despite days spent on looking for a solution on SO I haven't found any answer matching my problem :( I will be grateful for any tips.

Current first data frame:

```
+---+--------------------+--------------------+----+-----+--------+---------+--------+
| Id|        CreationDate|                Body|Year|Month|Day_of_Y|Week_of_Y|Year_adj|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+----+-----+--------+---------+--------+
|  1|2011-08-30 21:12:...|What open source ...|2011|    8|     242|       35|    2011|
|  2|2011-08-30 21:14:...|GPU mining is the...|2011|    8|     242|       35|    2011|
|  8|2011-08-30 21:18:...|I would like to d...|2011|    8|     242|       35|    2011|
|  9|2011-08-30 21:18:...|I didn't get it. ...|2011|    8|     242|       35|    2011|
| 10|2011-08-30 21:19:...|Poclbm: An open s...|2011|    8|     242|       35|    2011|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+----+-----+--------+---------+--------+
```

Second data frame (Loughran-McDonald dictionary):

```
+---------+--------+--------+-----------+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----+
|     Word|Negative|Positive|Uncertainty|Litigious|Constraining|Superfluous|Interesting|Modal|
+---------+--------+--------+-----------+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| aardvark|       0|       0|          0|        0|           0|          0|          0|    0|
| abalones|       0|       0|          0|        0|           0|          0|          0|    0|
|  abandon|    2009|       0|          0|        0|           0|          0|          0|    0|
+---------+--------+--------+-----------+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

One way (not sure if it's the most performant) is to create an actual python dictionary from your sentiment dictionary and apply it within a user defined function (UDF). Given that your sentiment dictionary has about 80k rows this should be feasible. Also by removing neutral words first you can further speed it out.
Code outline would be as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
# filter neutral words
filtered_sentiment_df = sentiment_df.filter((f.col("negative") > 0) | (f.col("positive") > 0))
# the following assumes that there are no words both positive and negative
sentiments = filtered_sentiment_df.select(f.col("word"), f.when(f.col("negative") > 0, -1).otherwise(1).alias("sentiment"))

# now we got the dict and can apply it via a UDF
sentiment_dict = {row["word"]: row["sentiment"] for row in sentiments.collect()}

def calculate_sentiment_score(sentence, sentiment_dict):
    return sum([sentiment_dict.get(w, 0) for w in sentence.split(" ")])

sentiment_udf = f.udf(lambda x: calculate_sentiment_score(x, sentiment_dict))
bodies_df = bodies_df.withColumn("total_sentiment", sentiment_udf(f.col("body")))
bodies_df.show()
```